# how to generate the root CA.pem in mongodb for configuring the ssl certificates?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am trying to configure the SSL certificates in the MongoDB community edition.

The configuration of my mongod.conf

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 
 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false
    allowInvalidHostnames: false
    disabledProtocols: TLS1_0,TLS1_1
```

Here what I am doing is converting certificate.crt and private.key as mongodb.pem and passing the ca_bundle.crt as CAFile in mongod.conf

I am trying to connect with the server using the command

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt --host myapptest.tk
```

Getting the error like

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.8
>
> connecting to: mongodb://myapptest.tk:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>
> 2019-04-04T19:57:40.401+0000 E NETWORK [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> 2019-04-04T19:57:40.402+0000 E QUERY [js] Error: couldn't connect to server myapptest.tk:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate :
>
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
>
> @(connect):2:6
>
> exception: connect failed

I want to know, how to create the root_CA.pem file and pass it as --sslCAFile?

where can found the ca.pem file in MongoDB?

Could anybody suggest me how to configure the SSL certificates in MongoDB?

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to generate the root CA.pem in mongodb for configuring the ssl
>   certificates?

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/appendix/security/appendixA-openssl-ca/) The procedure creates both the **`CA PEM`** file and an intermediate authority certificate and key files to sign server/client test certificates.

> **TESTING PURPOSES ONLY:**  This will provides some guidelines for creating test x.509 certificates:
>
> - Do not use these certificates for production. Instead, follow your    security policies.
> - For information on OpenSSL, refer to the official OpenSSL docs.    Although this tutorial uses OpenSSL, the material should not be taken 
>     as an authoritative reference on OpenSSL.

for further your ref [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/secure-mongodb-with-x-509-authentication)

Comment: hello Md Haidar Ali Khan. I took a reference as this link <http://demarcsek92.blogspot.com/2014/05/mongodb-ssl-setup.html> and generated the server.pem and client.pem. we are using both files to connect to the server here. Is there any alternatives to connect to the server by using client.pem?